# What is the best way to implement C#'s BackgroundWorker in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I use C#'s [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object frequently to start a thread and perform a task.  What's the easiest way to accomplish the same thing in Delphi?

Here's some code in C#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
  bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
  bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);
  test_number++;
  object[] arguments = { "test", test_number };
  bg.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
}

void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      // done.
}

void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     // do actual work here
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look into [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) by Primoz Gabrijelcic, or into [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=100) by Andreas Hausladen, which should both give you similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

for your solution this is: [delphi-components/backgroundworker](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/backgroundworker/) this component like c# backgroundworker's event, property etc.

Comment: Why the `(:` is there some problem with this component?

Comment: no no, no problem this component, cause this my first answer ok?

Comment: +1 I don't know this component, but given the fact that it has sourcecode it looks like something you can try.

Comment: Within 30 seconds of examining the source code of this component, I found it calls TerminateThread: a BIG no-no that always leads to undefined behavior.  That ended my investigation as now I don't trust this component to do the right thing without thorough review/revision.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811